# How to open URL from Fragment TextView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, url, hyperlink

I have an activity with multiple tabs and each tab consists of a fragment with some text inside. I would like to have a text with "Read More" which is a link to an URL. Without having the link, everything works fine, but when I try to implement it, I get

> E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException

So I assume it is the way I implement it. Right now, the fragment has this:

```js
public class About_us extends Fragment {

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_us, container, false);
    //The part below is For Read More
    TextView t2 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.read_more);
    if (t2 != null) {
      t2.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }

    return rootView;
  }
}
```

"read_more" layout has this for the TextView:

```js
< TextView
android: id = "@+id/read_more"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: clickable = "true"
android: text = "@string/link_to_the_website"
android: textColor = "@color/buttonColorPressed" / >
```

And link_to_website is given in the strings:

```js
< string name = "link_to_the_website" > < a href = "www.google.com/" > Read More Here < /a></string >
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what is it that I wrote wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Ether use your inflated view as

```
TextView t2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.read_more);
```

or override `onViewCreated` and then you can use `getView()` or directed passed view

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    TextView t2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.read_more);
    // or TextView t2 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.read_more);
}
```

**Because** `getview` will only return the actual view which was previously created and returned by `onCreateView` **otherwise it will return null**, hence the issue

[`getView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle))

> `Get the root view` for the fragment's layout (the `one returned by
>   onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle))`, if provided.

so you cannot use `getView` before the completion of `onCreateView`.
Then with this approach, you split the task into two parts

`onCreateView` : for view inflation

`onViewCreated`: for view and listeners initialization

update : to add links

```
t2.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
t2.setText(Html.fromHtml("< string name = 'link_to_the_website' > < a href = 'https://www.google.com/' > Read More Here < /a></string >"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice and detailed answer. I have tried with  TextView t2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.read_more);  and nothing happens. Please see the comment above. If I can't solve it this way, I will try it in another way

Comment: @CuriousPaul don't try the other way, won't change anything , i will update the answer for linking part

Comment: Thank you for staying with me on this problem. The good news is that the link works and opens the browser, which is great. The problem is that instead of Read More Here, it shows the whole line "< string name = 'link_to_the_website' > < a href = 'https://www.google.com/' > Read More Here < /a></string >"), but with google.com highlighted. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: @CuriousPaul try removing the `< string ...> </string>` pair, use `< a href = 'https://www.google.com' > Read More Here < /a>`

Comment: Did that. Now it shows underlined "Read More Here" as it should, but it doesn't do anything. This is what I have now: `t2.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href = 'www.google.com/' > Read More Here </a>"));` I imported also import android.text.Html;

Comment: No reaction whatsoever. I also removed `android:autoLink="web"` and `android:text` from the Layout. What else can I do?

Comment: @CuriousPaul it should be `t2.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href = 'https://www.google.com' > Read More Here </a>"));`

Comment: I even tried like this ` t2.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href='https://www.w3schools.com'>Visit W3Schools</a>"));`, using the lesson from https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp. No reaction

Comment: try adding `t2.setClickable(true);`

Answer (score 1):

try to change the line in your code

```
TextView t2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.read_more);
```

and add the property in your xml in textview

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

Comment: Thank you! 
This part: TextView t2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.read_more); solved the crashing problem, but adding autoLink actually kills the link. However, if I remove "web" it says "No apps can perform this action" when clicking

Answer (score 0):

```
// declare interface in fragment   
 public interface OnTextSelectedListener
  {
   void ontextSelected(String url);
  }

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
      super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (OnTextSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnTextSelectedListener");
    }
}

// Implement interface in activity


   public void ontextSelected(String   url) {
  // load your webview
   }
```

Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) to understand fragment communication better.

Comment: Thank you! Would this go after onCreateView? And should I keep the layout and the strings code the same?

Comment: onCreateView Call listner method and for better understanding read fragment communication. Accept my answer if it helped you.@CuriousPaul