# TextView link not working in my fragment with emulator

Tags: android, textview, fragment

I want to put a web link in my `TextView`. I am using the `TextView` in my fragment. I think it does not work on an emulator.  I changed the emulator and still got the same problem.

Here are the solutions I've tried:

1. [How to open URL from Fragment TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264229/how-to-open-url-from-fragment-textview)
2. [Android - Hyperlink is not clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914485/android-hyperlink-is-not-clickable)
3. [Why link does not work in the text view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571191/why-link-does-not-work-in-the-text-view/18571280)

**My `TextView` inside `linearLayout`**

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/privacy_policy"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/tv_privacy_policy" />
```

**My string value**

```
 <string name="privacy_policy">Privacy Policy<a href="https://csunix.mohawkcollege.ca/~000762465/Privacy%20Policy/ielts_up.html"></a></string>
```

**My `onCreateView()`**

```
      @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_aboutus, container, false);

        TextView tv_privacy_policy = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_privacy_policy);

//        Linkify.addLinks(tv_privacy_policy, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        tv_privacy_policy.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        String text = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Pricacy Policy</a>";
        tv_privacy_policy.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));

        return rootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**maybe this will help you:**

```
    SpannableString string = new SpannableString("Privacy Policy");
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://csunix.mohawkcollege.ca/~000762465/Privacy%20Policy/ielts_up.html"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    };
    string.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, string.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    textView.setText(string);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: where can i put my url??

Comment: @ArpitPatel you want open url in browser?

Comment: Yes but my question is where can i put my webpage url in? like in string or in java code

Comment: @ArpitPatel i fixed my answer with your url

Comment: I tried your solution but i can't even see my textView anymore.

Comment: I don't understand, what you want? Show image result you want.

Comment: I want textview clickable like link in fragment. If I click textview it will redirect to browser and open provided link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181376/discussion-between-serg3z-and-arpit-patel).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this following code and It's working fine, I have tested myself.

**Don't use android:autoLink tag attribute with it. Because it causes LinkMovementMethod doesn't work.**

```
    String textToShow="<a href=\"https://csunix.mohawkcollege.ca/~000762465/Privacy%20Policy/ielts_up.html\">Privacy Policy</a>";

        Spanned result;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            result = Html.fromHtml(textToShow,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
        } else {
            result = Html.fromHtml(textToShow);
        }
        textView.setText(result);
        textView. setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

If you are about to pass the string on XML then you can do something like this following

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/privacy_policy"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/tv_privacy_policy" />

    TextView tv_privacy_policy= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_privacy_policy);
    tv_privacy_policy.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

**Here is following the list of flags that may help you:**

```
    FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT = 63;
    FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY = 0;
    FROM_HTML_OPTION_USE_CSS_COLORS = 256;
    FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_BLOCKQUOTE = 32;
    FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_DIV = 16;
    FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_HEADING = 2;
    FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_LIST = 8;
    FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_LIST_ITEM = 4;
    FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_PARAGRAPH = 1;
```

Good luck. :)